# Symfony 4: I decorated UrlGeneratorInterface, but it's not used, it uses CompiledUrlGenerator instead

Tags: symfony, routes, decorator, symfony4, router

I decorated UrlGeneratorInterface

```
app.decorator.url_generator:
    class: App\CoreBundle\Routing\Extension\UrlGenerator
    decorates: Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface
    arguments: ['@app.decorator.url_generator.inner']
```

but it's not used in cases where some bundle in example executes $this->generator->generate(), and I tracked what Symfony does through XDebug and CompiledUrlGenerator is used instead. I can see where this happens, namely in  Symfony\Component\Routing\Router in getGenerator it specifically checks for CompiledUrlGenerator::class. But I don't want to override vanilla Symfony code. How am I supposed to override/decorate/extend which class in order for mine to be chosen always, as I have special parameters I need to add to the path. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.

```
app.decorator.router:
    class: App\CoreBundle\Routing\Extension\Router
    decorates: 'router.default'
    arguments: ['@app.decorator.router.inner']
```

Decorating this actually makes all packages use your Router. And as the UrlGenerator it has the generate function which can be extended.

EDIT: On request I provide the router class as well:

```
class Router implements RouterInterface {
    protected $innerRouter;
    public function __construct(RouterInterface $innerRouter) {
        $this->innerRouter = $innerRouter;
    }
    public function setContext(RequestContext $context)
    {
        $this->innerRouter->setContext($context);
    }
    public function getContext()
    {
        return $this->innerRouter->getContext();
    }
    public function getRouteCollection()
    {
        return $this->innerRouter->getRouteCollection();
    }
    public function generate($name, $parameters = [], $referenceType = self::ABSOLUTE_PATH)
    {
        //add here to $parameters...
        return $this->innerRouter->generate($name, $parameters, $referenceType);
    }
    public function match($pathinfo)
    {
        $parameters = $this->innerRouter->match($pathinfo);
        //add here to $parameters...
        return $parameters;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example for your Router class? I'm trying to do something similar but can't find a way.

Comment: I added my implementation of the Router class to the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm, I was having a hard time figuring this out.

Comment: yep, same here.